# Button is not visible at runtime(cocoa objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I am trying to load nib at run time. I am using Button control & binding it to one method & outlet.

But problem is that when i load it run time it not display button.

Also When i click on position where i placed button in interface builder, it executes binded method. I don't understand what is happening ?

Comment: Could it be possible that you have your view.hidden = YES applied to the button? hard to say without your code posted.

Comment: Yep, need a sample app that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sample code is about 3000 lines. I am running wizard with 2 buttons (one for next, one for previous),one label shows title of window,10 different steps that wizard navigate from one step to another step, for that i am using same window but using view for replacing description on window.I mean i have placed one view on main window. And all other views are in nib file. Each view have it's outlet which is used at runtime for replacing view.Also other view may contain button or textfield placed on it for retriveing data from user or performing some operation.

Comment: Any suggestion for this complex coding acceptable....

Comment: What other thing happening i tell you....When i remove binding of 'previous' button, previous button become visible & next button become invisible. After then i remove binding of 'next' button, 'next' button become visible & 'title' label become invisible.(binding means binding of only outlet, not remove binding of method)

Comment: You don't need to post all the Sample code just enough to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the exact problem. I am adding view like as below

```
[[NSWindow contentview] addsubview:newView];
```

This statement create so many problem. So i finally add one view & inside that view, insert one more view. Then replacing that view with other view. It works so fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you've not set up your auto-sizing "springs" correctly and the window is a different size when running than the design view in IB. Because of this, the button is whizzing right out of where it should be as soon as the window's size is set.

Comment: Turns out not to be the case here, but it may still be the cause of trouble for anybody searching in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This code will surely works.. If any friend needs

```
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/Users/mac/Desktop/logo/Forward.png"];

[_frwd_btn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```